# Not sure if code is perfectly written for bulkification inside invocable method

Tags: visual-workflow, invocable-method, bulkification

I have been reading a lot of bulkifying code inside of the invocable methods both here at stack exchange and outside. More reading has led to a lot of confusion and still not sure if I have done it correctly. I get more confused when I use [0] to access field values without knowing if it is the right way to do it.

The below code calls a record triggered flow, which in turn calls an invocable apex action when the status field on the record is changed. The below code will be run by multiple users from different workorders. Would appreciate any advice.

```
public with sharing class GenerateTxt {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Generate txt file' description='Test Description')
    public static void generateTxtFile(List<Requests> record) {
        
        List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
        List<String> workOrderIds = new List<String>();
        List<String> contactIds = new List<String>();
            
        for (Requests rec: record ) {
            accountIds.add(rec.workOrderRecord.AccountId);
            workOrderIds.add(rec.workOrderRecord.Id);
            contactIds.add(rec.workOrderRecord.ContactId);
        }

        List<ContentVersion> files = new List<ContentVersion>();

        List<WorkOrderLineItem> wols = [SELECT Part_Name__c FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE WorkOrderId IN :workOrderIds WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        for (Account rec :[SELECT ID, Name
                (SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber FROM WorkOrders WHERE Id IN :workOrderIds),
                (SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts WHERE Id IN :contactIds),
                (SELECT Id, Name FROM Equipments__r WHERE Account_Name__c IN :accountIds)
                FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]) {
            
            Person Person = new Person();
            Person.firstName = rec.Contacts[0].FirstName;          
            Person.equipmentModel = rec.Equipments__r[0].Name;

            //Incident Location
            IncidentLocation incidentLocation = new IncidentLocation();
            incidentLocation.landmark = rec.WorkOrders[0].Landmark__c;

            String fileName = ApexConstants.SERVICE_AUTH_REQ + ApexConstants.getMountainTimeZone(Datetime.now())+'.txt';
            String fileContent = ApexConstants.generateHeaderRecord('TA').toUpperCase() + '\n';

            ContentVersion file = new ContentVersion();
            file.Title = fileName;
            file.PathOnClient = fileName;
            file.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(fileContent);
            file.ContentLocation = 'S';
            files.add(file);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] insertFiles = Database.insert(files, true);
        files = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :files ORDER BY Id ASC];

        List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
        Integer counter = 0;
        for (Database.SaveResult result: insertFiles) {
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cdl.ContentDocumentId = files[counter].ContentDocumentId;
                cdl.LinkedEntityId = workOrderIds[0];
                contentDocumentLinks.add(cdl);
                counter++;
            }
        }
        insert contentDocumentLinks;          
    }

    public class Requests {
        @InvocableVariable(label='WorkOrder Record' description='WorkOrder Record without the dot' required=true)
        public WorkOrder workOrderRecord;
    }
    public class Person {
        public String firstName;
        public String equipmentModel;    
    } 
    public class IncidentLocation {
        public String landmark;  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cdl.LinkedEntityId = workOrderIds[0];
```

won't work in bulk; it will associate every document with a single work order, rather than having links to the work orders that were passed in.

You need to keep track of the file creation order and then populate the correct values. Here's my rough draft for this solution.

The new parts are as follows:

```
      Map<Id, Id> accountToWO = new Map<Id, Id>();
      Id[] queryAccountOrder = new Id[0];
```

...

```
          accountToWO.put(rec.Id, rec.WorkOrders[0].Id);
          queryAccountOrder.add(rec.Id);
```

...

```
      for (Id accountId: queryAccountOrder) {
          if (result.isSuccess()) {
              ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
              cdl.ContentDocumentId = files[counter].ContentDocumentId;
              cdl.LinkedEntityId = accountToWO.get(accountId);
              contentDocumentLinks.add(cdl);
              counter++;
          }
      }
```

Here's the complete listing, for reference.

```
public with sharing class GenerateTxt {
  @InvocableMethod(label='Generate txt file' description='Test Description')
  public static void generateTxtFile(List<Requests> record) {
      
      List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
      List<String> workOrderIds = new List<String>();
      List<String> contactIds = new List<String>();
          
      for (Requests rec: record ) {
          accountIds.add(rec.workOrderRecord.AccountId);
          workOrderIds.add(rec.workOrderRecord.Id);
          contactIds.add(rec.workOrderRecord.ContactId);
      }

      List<ContentVersion> files = new List<ContentVersion>();

      Map<Id, Id> accountToWO = new Map<Id, Id>();
      Id[] queryAccountOrder = new Id[0];

      List<WorkOrderLineItem> wols = [SELECT Part_Name__c FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE WorkOrderId IN :workOrderIds WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];

      for (Account rec :[SELECT ID, Name
              (SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber FROM WorkOrders WHERE Id IN :workOrderIds),
              (SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts WHERE Id IN :contactIds),
              (SELECT Id, Name FROM Equipments__r WHERE Account_Name__c IN :accountIds)
              FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]) {
          
          Person Person = new Person();
          Person.firstName = rec.Contacts[0].FirstName;          
          Person.equipmentModel = rec.Equipments__r[0].Name;

          //Incident Location
          IncidentLocation incidentLocation = new IncidentLocation();
          incidentLocation.landmark = rec.WorkOrders[0].Landmark__c;

          String fileName = ApexConstants.SERVICE_AUTH_REQ + ApexConstants.getMountainTimeZone(Datetime.now())+'.txt';
          String fileContent = ApexConstants.generateHeaderRecord('TA').toUpperCase() + '\n';

          ContentVersion file = new ContentVersion();
          file.Title = fileName;
          file.PathOnClient = fileName;
          file.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(fileContent);
          file.ContentLocation = 'S';
          files.add(file);

          accountToWO.put(rec.Id, rec.WorkOrders[0].Id);
          queryAccountOrder.add(rec.Id);
      }
      Database.insert(files, true);
      files = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :files ORDER BY Id ASC];

      List<ContentDocumentLink> contentDocumentLinks = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
      Integer counter = 0;
      for (Id accountId: queryAccountOrder) {
          if (result.isSuccess()) {
              ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
              cdl.ContentDocumentId = files[counter].ContentDocumentId;
              cdl.LinkedEntityId = accountToWO.get(accountId);
              contentDocumentLinks.add(cdl);
              counter++;
          }
      }
      insert contentDocumentLinks;          
  }

  public class Requests {
      @InvocableVariable(label='WorkOrder Record' description='WorkOrder Record without the dot' required=true)
      public WorkOrder workOrderRecord;
  }
  public class Person {
      public String firstName;
      public String equipmentModel;    
  } 
  public class IncidentLocation {
      public String landmark;  
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to be concerned about taking the first element from a list with `[0]`; only appropriate when you can guarantee that there is only one element or that the ordering is appropriate so that the first element is the one you need. One of the challenges in bulkification is the 10,000 rows limit. Another is logic where the CPU time grows exponentially.

*Note that I do not know what you are trying to accomplish here; this is more a comment on the general approach.*

But assuming you are within the 10,000 rows then I suggest changing to 3 separate queries e.g. the first one:

```
Map<Id, WorkOrders> wos = new Map<Id, WorkOrders>([
    SELECT Id, WorkOrderNumber, Account.Id, Account.Name
    FROM WorkOrder
    WHERE Id IN :workOrderIds
]);
```

where all the records are grabbed and a reference to the parent Account is included. Then you can reference the SObjects for each request and generate the output you need from those:

```
for (Requests rec: record) {
    WorkOrder wo = wos.get(rec.workOrderRecord.Id);
    Contact contact = ...
    Equipment__c equipment = ...
    ...
}
```

This keeps the rows queried to a minimum and keeps the CPU time linearly dependent on the number of rows rather than it growing exponentially because the maps are used.

Comment: If there can be more than one input and the return type isn't void, there must be the same number of responses, in the same order, as the inputs so the right result can be returned to the correct interview instance.